# firebase android class-based updates not respecting case of the field names

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have the following class declared (note the case choice):

```
public class User{

    private String DisplayName;
    private Boolean Proxy = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public User(){

    }
    public User(String DisplayName, Boolean Proxy) {
        this.DisplayName = DisplayName;
        this.Proxy = Proxy;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return DisplayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String DisplayName) {
        this.DisplayName = DisplayName;
    }

    public Boolean getProxy() {
        return Proxy;
    }
}
```

I then call:

```
ref.child("People/123").setValue(userList);
```

where `userList` is an instance of `ArrayList<User>`

However the nodes created do not respect the capitalization as I would imagine it to do. They create `displayName` and `proxy` instead of the expected `DisplayName` and `Proxy` to match the declaration.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to make it such that it ***does*** respect the field name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to assume that the names in the Firebase storage are based on your fields `DisplayName` and `Proxy`.

But if you read [the documentation on `setValue`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_setValue) it says:

> The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized

This reads like Firebase uses [the Java bean definition of properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) (since Java doesn't have native properties), which means they are derived from the (public) method names `getDisplayName` and `getProxy`.

To determine the property name from `getDisplayName` you strip the `get` prefix and make the first letter after that lowercase. And that leads exactly to the property names you're seeing in your Firebase storage.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! But, I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. I'm a little new at firebase/java. You'll have to be patient with my ignorance. So you're saying that this is an expected behavior then? Then if I wanted it to display as "DisplayName", what exactly should I do?

Comment: In my answer is a link to the Java tutorial section on Java Beans, which you really should read. I don't know of a way to have an uppercase first character in a property name. That's simply not how Java Bean properties are defined. For display purposes I would recommend separating the "what property name to store the value in?" from "what label to display?".

Comment: I see. So then this is expected behaviour for what firebase does on a class based  `.setValue();` Ok! Thanks, that was very helpful.