# Android Firebase dictionary keys changing case

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-filterable

I am using Firebase Database and bellow specified is my java class structure. After saving my first object in Firebase database I realised that the keys are automatically converted to lower case keys in Firebase database. is there any solution to retain the case while saving my objects.

```
public class Student {

String NAME;

String ROLL_NUMBER;

String USER_NAME;

String MAIL_ID;

String PASSWORD;


public Student() {
}

public Student(String NAME, String ROLL_NUMBER, String PASSWORD, String MAIL_ID, String USER_NAME) {
    this.NAME = NAME;
    this.ROLL_NUMBER = ROLL_NUMBER;
    this.PASSWORD = PASSWORD;
    this.MAIL_ID = MAIL_ID;
    this.USER_NAME = USER_NAME;
}

public String getNAME() {
    return NAME;
}

public String getROLL_NUMBER() {
    return ROLL_NUMBER;
}

public String getPASSWORD() {
    return PASSWORD;
}

public String getMAIL_ID() {
    return MAIL_ID;
}

public String getUSER_NAME() {
    return USER_NAME;
}
```

}

I have also tried with  `@SerializedName` also doesn't make any difference.
Here is key value pairs in Firebase database

```
"-LMqLmS09gGKjR-s9CML" : {
  "mail_ID" : "gyana@gmail.com",
  "name" : "Gyanaranjan",
  "password" : "123456",
  "roll_NUMBER" : "1001028",
  "user_NAME" : "gyan1028"
}, 
 "-LMqMPegnxHp8l4efj_J" : {
  "mail_ID" : "shyamu@gmail.com",
  "name" : "Shyama G",
  "password" : "113456",
  "roll_NUMBER" : "1001056",
  "user_NAME" : "shyamla1056"
}
```

[here is the screenshot of firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q28X.png)

Comment: Please show us the code that you are using to add the data to the database.

Comment: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
String key = myRef.push().getKey();
Student student = new Student(name, rollNumber, password, mail,userName);
                myRef.child(key).setValue(student);

Comment: Have you tried to remove the old data and add fresh data and see if you have the same behaviour?

Comment: The answer/explanation for why this is happening is available in following link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292731/firebase-android-class-based-updates-not-respecting-case-of-the-field-names/26298046#26298046

but There is no way available to insert the UPPER CASE keys  into the Firebase database system. where as in iOS they can achieve the with ease.

Comment: Which link are you talking about?

Comment: please check the previous coment

Comment: So you solved the problem?

Comment: no solution yet..it will be great if you have any solution.

Comment: So the explanation in that link didn't helped you?

Comment: I tried keeping the properties public and removing the public getters and it worked 
But again is it safe to use public propeties???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, you need to know that Firebase real-time database follows the `Java Bean` property naming convention for mapping between the Java object and the fields in the node.

Here are some examples of how specific method names map to property names (and this field names):

```
public String getName(); // getter for property "name"
public void setName(String name); // setter for property "name"

public String getRollNumber(); // getter for property "rollNumber"
public void setRollNumber(String rollNumber); // setter for property "rollNumber"
```

It is not mandatory to use `getters` and `setters`. In all of these cases you can also go without the getter/setter and use **only** a **public** field:

```
public String name;
public String rollNumber;
```

Which is perfectly safe. So it is not required to have both getters and setters. If you have **only** a getter, Firebase will set the corresponding field directly. This *does* however require that your field name follows the naming conventions, so that Firebase can find the correct field to set.

For another information, you can also take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423501/firebase-read-getter-setter/51424698).

Answer (score 1):

```
if you removed the public getters and make the properties as public you will be able to save any Desired case keys.

public class Student {

public String NAME;

public String ROLL_NUMBER;

public String USER_NAME;

public String MAIL_ID;

public String PASSWORD;


public Student() {
}

public Student(String NAME, String ROLL_NUMBER, String PASSWORD, String MAIL_ID, `enter code here`String USER_NAME) {
    this.NAME = NAME;
    this.ROLL_NUMBER = ROLL_NUMBER;
    this.PASSWORD = PASSWORD;
    this.MAIL_ID = MAIL_ID;
    this.USER_NAME = USER_NAME;
}
```

}

```
and now you will see the Database with Desired case Key

"-LMqfKkyWC189gaiR1jJ" : {
      "MAIL_ID" : "shreya@gmail.com",
      "NAME" : "Shreya",
      "PASSWORD" : "123456",
      "ROLL_NUMBER" : "1001027",
      "USER_NAME" : "shreya1027"
    }
```

[Here is the Firebase database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc4rL.png)